# Spring Security LDAP. The SearchControls.OBJECT_SCOPE is used instead of SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap

spring-boot-starter-security 2.2.4.RELEASE, jdk 11

The org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForMultipleAttributeValues method is used for the group search during the web request authentication. The request passed the authentification. However, no user groups are found.

It uses the search controls with the scope SearchControls.OBJECT_SCOPE. The search controls prepared by the following method 
com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.LdapCtx.c_getAttributes.(Name name, String[] attrIds,
                                      Continuation cont)
As the result no any groups are found.
If I using the ldap template for the search with the same input (group search base, group search filter, group role attribute) but with the SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE all groups are found.

What I need to change in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder configuration to use the SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE for the group search?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you calling `SpringSecurityLdapTemplate` directly or is it through something like an `LdapAuthoritiesPopulator`?

Comment: Yes. I directly created the template to check what it returns with the same configuration.

Comment: `SpringSecurityLdapTemplate` uses `SUBTREE_SCOPE` by default, so I guess I'm not clear on what you are asking. If you are constructing it directly, then you can always call `setSearchControls` with whatever you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a configuration issue. The original group search base pointed on the root node. This is why search via LDAP template with SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE allowed find groups from the child nodes. Not sure why the com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.LdapCtx.c_getAttributes uses the SearchControls.OBJECT_SCOPE as the default value.
Changing the group search base to the specific group node solved the issue.